# Java: ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I have this error when i try to do

```
data[i][1]=tmp[1];
```

Or any int > 0 in `tmp[]`. However `donne` contains 5 parts separated by `:__:`. Also if I do `System.out.println(tmp[1]);` it will print the right thing and then throw the exception. Here is the code:

```
String[] donne=toServ.getDonneAccueil();
System.out.println(donne[0]);
// Données test
Object[][] data = new Object[donne.length][6];
for(int i=0;i<donne.length;i++){
    final int k;
    String[] tmp=donne[i].split(":__:");
    /*System.out.println(tmp[0]);
    System.out.println(tmp[1]);
    System.out.println(tmp[2]);
    System.out.println(tmp[3]);
    */
    data[i][0]=tmp[0];
    data[i][1]=tmp[1];
    data[i][2]="n";
    data[i][3]=tmp[2];
    data[i][4]=tmp[3];
```

The Stack Trace is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Vue_Accueil.<init>(Vue_Accueil.java:60)
    at Menu$1.mouseClicked(Menu.java:65)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please give us example input and expected output.

Comment: print the value of `donne.length` and check what it is

Comment: an example input would be      donne[i]="testscenar:__:0:__:05:14:12:__:14:14:19:__:1".
donne.length says 3

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));`

Comment: Now show us the full stack trace.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I have just put one but it print [testscenar, 0, 05:14:12, 14:14:19, 1] and another line with[null]

Comment: I strongly suspect that the input *isn't* like that in the case that's failing. Print `donne[i]` before you split it...

Comment: Are you sure `data[i][1]` isn't out of bounds?

Comment: the results of the print(donne[i]): testscenar:__:0:__:05:14:12:__:14:14:19:__:1
null
it's as if between 1 and null was a \n

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Object[][] data = new Object[donne.length][6];
So i don't think

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data[i]));` just to be sure.

Comment: It print 
[testscenar:__:0:__:05:14:12:__:14:14:19:__:1, null, null]
[testscenar:__:0:__:05:14:12:__:14:14:19:__:1, null, null]
However it should consist in:
[testscenar:__:0:__:05:14:12:__:14:14:19:__:1]

Comment: Ok I have found the error, I was adding 2 "null" on another part of the code, thanks all